# SignalR Authentication through AuthToken in Connection Header

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr, signalr-hub

I made BasicAuth and WindowsAuth work in my SignalR project.
Now I am looking for other ways of authenticating (without needing a Win/AD Account).

While reading the SignalR documentation I stumbled upon the possibility to provide auth tokens in the connection header:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#header

It states "Then, in the hub, you would verify the user's token."
I could make the OnConnected method to be access anonymously and get the token like the following and then verifying it:

```
var test = Context.Request.Headers["mytoken"];
```

But what would would be the next step? I would need to set the connected user to be an authenticated user but how can I do that manually?

My overall goal is to have a very simple method of authentication,i.e. a "hardcoded" token validated on the server side and grant access to the other methods which have authorization enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. I found a kind of workaround creating a new AuthorizeAttribute. Next, I decorated the methods with this attribute. When a request is made, the attribute checks the token and gives the permission or not to be accessed.
Here is the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
internal class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        string token = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Headers["AuthenticationToken"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return false;
        else
        {
            string decryptedValue = Encryptor.Decrypt(token, Encryptor.Password);

            string[] values = decryptedValue.Split(';');

            string userName = values[0],
                deviceId = values[1],
                connectionId = values[2];

            bool b = ...CanAccess()...;

            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

To have a username, you can simply add a property in your Hub that reads the token, parse it and returns the username.
Still can't use Context.User.Identity, though. I hope it helps.